# Is it possible to set the Capistrano rvm_type variable depending on the server?

Tags: capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I have 2 servers I need to deploy to, one has a RVM installed in user mode the other in system mode. I can I write a deployment script for both?

In other words is there a way to set rvm_type to:user for one server and to :system for the other server?

Comment: +1 Great question. I wonder why this was down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do it yet, but you should open a [ticket for rvm-capistrano](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/issues) with a request for auto detection, I do not think it will be added shortly - but it's worth consideration and possibly can be implemented.

You could try this workaround:

```
set :rvm_path, "$(
  [ -x /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ] && echo /usr/local/rvm || 
  [ -x $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm     ] && echo $HOME/.rvm     || 
  false
)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it different because, for instance, your production server differs from the qa server, you could just define it in the deploy/.rb files, instead of the deploy.rb file. I've done this with many stage-specific settings.